# Python IF statement always return True

Tags: python, if-statement

This is a very small version of my script. I changed it to test the if statement.
The value of the Boolean is False and that's right! When I change the value of row, highRisk always receive the correct value (True/False).
But even with the correct value of highRisk the result is always "ok". Does anyone can explain me why?

```
row = 5

riskHigh = (reasons.iloc[row,1:2] == "high").bool

if riskHigh:
    print "ok"
else:
    print "oops"
```

Results:

```
In [60]: row = 5
    ...: riskHigh = (reasons.iloc[row,1:2] == "high").bool
    ...: 
    ...: if riskHigh:
    ...:     print "ok"
    ...: else:
    ...:     print "oops"
    ...: 
    ...: 
ok

In [61]: print riskHigh
<bound method Series.bool of Risk_Rating    False
Name: 5, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 5):

As the print says, riskHigh is a method. You should call the method:

```
riskHigh = (reasons.iloc[row,1:2] == "high").bool()
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! It seems that the "()" afoter .bool fixed the problem.